# How can I move/copy contacts from Exchange to Google within Contacts?

Tags: iphone, contacts, exchange-activesync

I'm using the Contacts app on my iPhone, some of my contacts are synced with a corporate exchange account, some with my private Google account. I want to ensure all contacts are synced with Google account as I might loose those who are added with exchange account when I leave the company.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26962/how-to-sync-gmail-contacts-keeping-exchange-contacts?rq=1

Comment: That edit should be classed as a new question, albeit duplicate...